# Insert / Overwrite mode in terminal of IntelliJ/PhpStorm

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, phpstorm

While I am using the terminal in IntelliJ or PhpStorm my cursor keeps switching to overwrite mode and I can't work out why.

It only started doing this within the last month and I made no configuration setting changes myself.

If I restart the IDE the mode is set back to insert which is correct.

I can confirm that switching the cursor mode in an editor window works fine but I can't find any bindings for toggling the functionality in the terminal window.

This is on OSX Sierra, I doubt it's yet another Sierra bug though as it doesn't appear to happen in other applications.

Does anyone have any idea why this would keep switching? All I can think of is that some key combination is changing it without me realising but if so the binding must have been changed in a recent update or something.

Comment: Same issue for me..

Comment: @prometheus does this get triggered for you when you hold down the left arrow to move the cursor back along a line of text? Seems to trigger it for me if I hold it down for a number of seconds.

Comment: I solved the problem... I had done some changes to the prompt in .bash_profile that cause this behavior. By removing it everything works fine again.

Comment: @prometheus - seeing this issue too, what changes did you make to *.bash_profile*?

Comment: @prometheus, looks like it is working for me too. I had incorrectly set my prompt too. If you add an answer I can give you credit.

Comment: @LeonRoy it's the PS1 variable which controls it. You can use something like http://bashrcgenerator.com/ to generate or check yours.

Comment: @chrismacp odd, even the simplest generated PS1 from bashrcgenerator *export PS1="\u@\h:\w\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"* is exhibiting the issue.

Comment: This just started happening for me again so I guess that previous idea didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this happens but the solution is to remove any modification to the prompt (PS1) in your ~/.bash_profile or wherever you have done such a modification.

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn off Vim emulator.
You can go to: Tools -> Turn off Vim Emulator

If Vim emulator is enabled then you can use the features of IDE (Pycharm or IntelliJ) along with the quick and easy editing of Vim.

So, all those who love vi or vim, I would suggest them to keep this enabled.